Laravel BadMethodCall Exception
I'm running a website on server using php-fpm, nginx. It is using Laravel Framework. Randomly server stopped working and start giving me BadMethodCall Exception. But there is no method listed in there.
/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php:71
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::()

I checked the memory on server and have 30 gb of free memory.
Complete stacktrace of earlier instance. Everytime it is form different place.
{
    "message": "Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::()",
    "exception": "BadMethodCallException",
    "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php",
    "line": 71,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php",
            "line": 3538,
            "function": "throwBadMethodCallException",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php",
            "line": 23,
            "function": "__call",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
            "line": 1660,
            "function": "forwardCallTo",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php",
            "line": 23,
            "function": "__call",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 2132,
            "function": "forwardCallTo",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasRelationships.php",
            "line": 87,
            "function": "__call",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/app/Models/Device/Device.php",
            "line": 52,
            "function": "hasOne",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php",
            "line": 539,
            "function": "site",
            "class": "App\\Models\\Device\\Device",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php",
            "line": 491,
            "function": "getRelationshipFromMethod",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php",
            "line": 440,
            "function": "getRelationValue",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 2029,
            "function": "getAttribute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/app/Http/Controllers/Api/V1/AuthController.php",
            "line": 107,
            "function": "__get",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/app/Http/Controllers/Api/V1/AuthController.php",
            "line": 102,
            "function": "checkDeviceIsOrphan",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\V1\\AuthController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/app/Http/Controllers/Api/V1/AuthController.php",
            "line": 89,
            "function": "checkDeviceIsActive",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\V1\\AuthController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/app/Http/Controllers/Api/V1/AuthController.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "checkDevice",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\V1\\AuthController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/app/Http/Controllers/Api/V1/AuthController.php",
            "line": 38,
            "function": "validateDevice",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\V1\\AuthController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "validation",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\Api\\V1\\AuthController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
            "line": 45,
            "function": "callAction",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
            "line": 262,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
            "line": 205,
            "function": "runController",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 721,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 128,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php",
            "line": 24,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Middleware\\RedirectIfAuthenticated",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/app/Http/Middleware/ApiSetLocale.php",
            "line": 29,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Middleware\\ApiSetLocale",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/app/Http/Middleware/ApiDataLogger.php",
            "line": 49,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Middleware\\ApiDataLogger",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php",
            "line": 50,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 127,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php",
            "line": 63,
            "function": "handleRequest",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 723,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 698,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 662,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 651,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 128,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php",
            "line": 31,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php",
            "line": 40,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TrimStrings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php",
            "line": 86,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 167,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 103,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 142,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 111,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/site/public/index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}

Device.php
<?php
/**
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * 
 **/
namespace App\Models\Device;

use App\Models\Lookups\Country;
use App\Models\Lookups\Language;
use App\Models\Site\Site;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;

class Device extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens;

    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @varstring
     */
    // 

    /**
     * The primary key associated with the table.
     *
     * @varstring
     */
    // 

    /**
     * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = true;

    const CREATED_AT = 'dt_created_at';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'dt_updated_at';

    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:sO';

    protected $fillable = [
        //
    ];

    public function site()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Site::class, 'cid', 'cid');
    }

    public function language()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Language::class);
    }

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Country::class);
    }

    //
    // 
}


ForwardCalls.php
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Support\Traits;

use BadMethodCallException;
use Error;

trait ForwardsCalls
{
    /**
     * Forward a method call to the given object.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $object
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     */
    protected function forwardCallTo($object, $method, $parameters)
    {
        try {
            return $object->{$method}(...$parameters);
        } catch (Error|BadMethodCallException $e) {
            $pattern = '~^Call to undefined method (?P<class>[^:]+)::(?P<method>[^\(]+)\(\)$~';

            if (! preg_match($pattern, $e->getMessage(), $matches)) {
                throw $e;
            }

            if ($matches['class'] != get_class($object) ||
                $matches['method'] != $method) {
                throw $e;
            }

            static::throwBadMethodCallException($method);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Forward a method call to the given object, returning $this if the forwarded call returned itself.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $object
     * @param  string  $method
     * @param  array  $parameters
     * @return mixed
     *
     * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     */
    protected function forwardDecoratedCallTo($object, $method, $parameters)
    {
        $result = $this->forwardCallTo($object, $method, $parameters);

        if ($result === $object) {
            return $this;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Throw a bad method call exception for the given method.
     *
     * @param  string  $method
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \BadMethodCallException
     */
    protected static function throwBadMethodCallException($method)
    {
        throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
            'Call to undefined method %s::%s()', static::class, $method
        ));
    }
}


PHP-FPM error logs
[22-Jul-2024 06:39:01] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[22-Jul-2024 06:39:01] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[22-Jul-2024 06:39:01] WARNING: [pool www] ACL set, listen.owner = 'nginx' is ignored
[22-Jul-2024 06:39:01] WARNING: [pool www] ACL set, listen.group = 'nginx' is ignored
[22-Jul-2024 06:39:01] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 32303
[22-Jul-2024 06:39:01] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[22-Jul-2024 06:39:01] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[22-Jul-2024 06:59:54] WARNING: [pool www] child 2214 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 576.972583 seconds from start
[22-Jul-2024 06:59:54] NOTICE: [pool www] child 12026 started
[22-Jul-2024 07:53:21] WARNING: [pool www] child 2927 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 3730.584780 seconds from start
[22-Jul-2024 07:53:21] NOTICE: [pool www] child 31509 started
[22-Jul-2024 07:55:15] WARNING: [pool www] child 5358 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 3679.467726 seconds from start
[22-Jul-2024 07:55:15] NOTICE: [pool www] child 687 started
[22-Jul-2024 08:14:01] WARNING: [pool www] child 7005, script '/var/www/site/public/index.php' (request: "POST /index.php") executing too slow (927.563321 sec), logging
[22-Jul-2024 08:14:01] NOTICE: child 7005 stopped for tracing
[22-Jul-2024 08:14:01] NOTICE: about to trace 7005
[22-Jul-2024 08:14:01] NOTICE: finished trace of 7005
[22-Jul-2024 08:19:01] WARNING: [pool www] child 7005, script '/var/www/site/public/index.php' (request: "POST /index.php") execution timed out (1227.563802 sec), terminating
[22-Jul-2024 08:19:01] WARNING: [pool www] child 7005 exited on signal 15 (SIGTERM) after 5016.207445 seconds from start
[22-Jul-2024 08:19:01] NOTICE: [pool www] child 14102 started
[22-Jul-2024 14:58:49] WARNING: [pool www] child 20921 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 226.940769 seconds from start
[22-Jul-2024 14:58:49] NOTICE: [pool www] child 25595 started
[22-Jul-2024 08:19:01] NOTICE: [pool www] child 14102 started
[22-Jul-2024 14:58:49] WARNING: [pool www] child 20921 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 226.940769 seconds from start
[22-Jul-2024 14:58:49] NOTICE: [pool www] child 25595 started
[22-Jul-2024 14:59:58] WARNING: [pool www] child 21778 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 254.525369 seconds from start
[22-Jul-2024 14:59:58] NOTICE: [pool www] child 26965 started
[22-Jul-2024 14:59:58] WARNING: [pool www] child 5433 said into stderr: "zend_mm_heap corrupted"
[22-Jul-2024 14:59:58] WARNING: [pool www] child 5433 exited with code 1 after 29157.541403 seconds from start
[22-Jul-2024 14:59:58] NOTICE: [pool www] child 26967 started
[22-Jul-2024 14:59:58] WARNING: [pool www] child 32315 said into stderr: "zend_mm_heap corrupted"
[22-Jul-2024 14:59:58] WARNING: [pool www] child 32315 exited with code 1 after 30057.394992 seconds from start
[22-Jul-2024 14:59:58] NOTICE: [pool www] child 26969 started
[22-Jul-2024 15:01:45] WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers), spawning 8 children, there are 4 idle, and 41 total children


You'll need to provide more info for us to help you out. Please provide the full stack trace and include the line of code from your application ( not from the vendor folder ) where the error occurs

@ArunAS I have added the stacktrace of another instance.

Give us Forwards.php file, the issue is there

@devsead I have added the file. The code works fine. We're running this on 8 ec2 instances. Suddenly daily one of 8 server started giving the error. I have also added the php-fpm errors from that time.
